# Writing PHP extension with C++

Tags: php, c++

PHP's core is written in C. But there are (I think) wrappers in C++ to make extension development possible for C++ programmers.

Now doesn't the speed suck if we use C++ to write PHP extensions? Because then the C++ has to be converted into C and then executed properly (I think, if I'm wrong then correct me).

Comment: This question is precise and not-general, I still don't know why some people down-vote still.

Comment: And I don't understand why people pity-upvote this. This is anything but precise. Where do you take the wishy-washy generalization about performance from? Where did you profile a specific implementation?

Comment: When I say " C++ has to be converted into C and then executed properly " it means that I'm thinking in a certain way about what I have questioned, and the answer given below then corrects me. If your mind is fool-blooded to down-vote on every question that does not match against your criteria then you should think otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions written in C++ will only be marginally slower than those written in C, due to the language overhead.  However, they will still be much faster than writing directly in PHP.

It's not the case the the C++ is "converted into C and then executed properly" - PHP's C source code is compiled down to machine language.  Extensions written in C++ are also compiled to machine language.